# What is the tech term of "layered DFS" (aka DFS up to 5 layers first, then BFS, then DFS again...etc)

Tags: algorithm

I recall there is such a algorithm between DFS and BFS, which will first do DFS until X-depth layer, then do BFS until all nodes go to X-depth layer, then will start do DFS of X+1 to 2X-depth layer...etc

(good at real world cases to avoid the worst case situation compared to the DFS or BFS, more like a mix of it)

Comment: I wonder if you're thinking of https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Iterative_deepening_depth-first_search? But if so, your description of it isn't quite accurate; that's a variant of DFS that lets you find the closest/shallowest matching node (as you would with BFS) without using as much memory as BFS requires.

Comment: Hey, this is exact the term I am looking for and you r correct, the description is not 100% match to the algorithm itself. Thanks